# ¿Cómo enviar mails con "mailto" de Javascript?

Tags: jquery

Quería saber como enviar mails con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y que dentro del mail tengo un subject y un cuerpo para poder escribir.

Mi duda es como agregar inputs a la función se que seria algo así:

```
 $('#input1').val()
```

A la función de Jquery que es la siguiente

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(location).attr('href', 'mailto:?subject='
                         + encodeURIComponent("This is my subject")
                         + "&body=" 
                         + encodeURIComponent("This is my body")
    );
});
```

Comment: le cambiaría el titulo a la pregunta, porque técnicamente no enviaras ningún email con mailto, si no que abrirás una aplicación que realmente lo haga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es posible enviar un email únicamente con Javascript, necesitas un lenguaje "server-side" que reciba la información (por ejemplo PHP) para poder realizar el envio.

Únicamente puedes abrir el cliente de correo del usuario, que es lo que haces con el código actual.

---

En cuanto a agregar los valores de inputs al href, simplemente cambia los textos por la función de jQuery que nombras:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'mailto:?subject='
                         + encodeURIComponent($('#input1').val())
                         + "&body=" 
                         + encodeURIComponent($('#input2').val())
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.